# expectation of X|X>0

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Suppose that you are studying a standard normal random variable represented by $X$∼$N(0,1)$. You are curious about the expected value of $X$ given that $X$ is greater than $0$. Can you determine what is $E[X∣X>0]$ ?

Source: [puzzledquant.com](https://www.puzzledquant.com/problems/clhudgq65002gmm08on3xaoq4)

My approach: How do I get f(x) for this X|X>0? Like I understand we have to integrate from 0 to \infinity xf(x), but I am unable to find the f(x) for this?